# Magento 2 - Tax remove from Grand Total

Tags: magento-2.1, tax

How to i'll tax calculate in Magento 2. My tax prices is already added in catalog products prices. I just want to show 5% Vat tax on subtotal but don't want to add in Subtotal and Grand Total. Please help me regarding this issue. Thanks in advance. Please check below screenshot what's showing right now. subtotal and tax is showeing is ok but adding in Total.[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display subtotal without tax.

Navigate to **Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Tax** and under section called "Shopping Cart Display Settings" you can decide how to display tax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Include Tax In Order Total.
admin >> store >> configuration >> sole >> tax and under section called "Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings" you can decide Include Tax In Order Total or not